# Asynchronous Webrequest best practices

Tags: .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

What is the best practice for getting a webrequest asynchronously?

I want to download a page from the internet (doesn't matter what)
and avoid blocking a thread as much as possible.

Previously I believed that it was enough to just use the 'BeginGetResponse' and 'EndGetResponse' pair.  But on closer inspection I also see that there is the option of using 'BeginGetRequestStream'

**[UPDATE]** GetRequestStream is used for POST operations

And then to add to the confusion, Should I be using stream.BeginRead and EndRead?

**[UPDATE]** this [article](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx) suggests it is even better to process the HttpResponse.GetResponseStream asynchronously using Stream.BeginRead

What a mess!

Can someone point me in the right direction?

What is the Best Practice?

Answer (score 5):

You could code this all yourself or you could just use WebClient which does a lot of the grunt work for you. For example, to download file as a string you would call DownloadStringAsync() which eventually will trigger the OnDowloadStringCompleted event. If the file is binary you might try using DownloadDataAsync() instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use Begin/EndGetResponse to asynchonously wait for the HTTP response.  If you are doing a POST and need to send a lot of data asynchronously, use Begin/EndGetRequestStream.
2. This isn't unique to asynchronous communication - you can look up the synchronous versions to get additional info.
3. I'm not sure why you would be doing a Read on the request stream - most likely you'll be writing to it, and reading from the Response stream.

Finally, [Jeffrey Richter's blog](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/default.aspx) has an article about some of the subtleties of HttpWebRequest and streams.

Comment: yes i think i was confused with the purpose of 'BeginGetRequestStream'

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing the web request in a new thread?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx

Comment: starting a new thread is less than ideal. Simply Blocking another thread isn't helping this application to scale